# How to Create a Tree with Ancestry Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Im creating an online retail store.

Trying to create a category tree using Ancestry Gem.

I used this tutorial as a guide and even used scaffolding. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDLn0V_AYgs

How do i make a tree? I have read the Gem's github page but im still confused.

**I just need my index.html.erb view to look like this.**

Parent

- Child
- Child
- Child

Parent

- Child
- Child

Parent

- Child
- Child
- Child
- Child

Currently my tree looks like this.

[image]

Controller.

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_category, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /categories
  # GET /categories.json
  def index
    @categories = Category.all
  end

  # GET /categories/1
  # GET /categories/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /categories/new
  def new
    @category = Category.new
  end

  # GET /categories/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /categories
  # POST /categories.json
  def create
    @category = Category.new(category_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @category.save
        format.html { redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @category }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /categories/1
  # PATCH/PUT /categories/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @category.update(category_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @category }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /categories/1
  # DELETE /categories/1.json
  def destroy
    @category.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to categories_url, notice: 'Category was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_category
      @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def category_params
      params.require(:category).permit(:name, :parent_id)
    end
end
```

Model

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_ancestry
end
```

View index.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Listing Categories</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Ancestry</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @categories.each do |category| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= category.name %></td>
        <td><%= category.ancestry %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', category %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_category_path(category) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', category, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Category', new_category_path %>
```

Rails Console. Category.last

```
 Category Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories"  ORDER BY "categories"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<Category id: 6, name: "HTC", ancestry: "1", created_at: "2015-07-21 10:45:54", updated_at: "2015-07-21 11:06:20">
```

Comment: Did you generate the migration?

Comment: @ProsenjitSaha yes i did that.

Comment: Then I think you are not attaching any parent to the category. Can you run ``Category.last`` in rails console and paste the results here?

Comment: @ProsenjitSaha thanks i just added it.