# Creating A Nested Category List

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Im creating an online retail store. Im trying to create a Category List. I have been able to make a category list but i need subcategories in a nested tree like structure.

Such as the following:

Mobile Phones

- Apple
- HTC
- Samsung

Laptops

- Sony
- Apple

I have tried for 8 hours now and just keep getting stuck.

Im really stuck.

I tried Ancestry Gem.

**How would you go about doing this in detail, even step by step would be great?**

There are some tutorials but none that i can find that are directly show what im trying to do.

My Database schema.rb as requested.

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150721095122) do

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "ancestry"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "categories", ["ancestry"], name: "index_categories_on_ancestry"

  create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.decimal  "price"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
  end

  add_index "items", ["user_id", "created_at"], name: "index_items_on_user_id_and_created_at"
  add_index "items", ["user_id"], name: "index_items_on_user_id"

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "remember_digest"
    t.boolean  "admin",               default: false
    t.string   "activation_digest"
    t.boolean  "activated",           default: false
    t.datetime "activated_at"
    t.string   "reset_digest"
    t.string   ">"
    t.datetime "reset_sent_at"
    t.string   "avatar_file_name"
    t.string   "avatar_content_type"
    t.integer  "avatar_file_size"
    t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"
    t.text     "description"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true

end
```

Comment: Could you also post how is your database structure?

Comment: "I tried Ancestry Gem" -- a-a-and? How did that go? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: @D-side The problem i had is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31559244/how-to-create-a-tree-with-ancestry-gem

Comment: @Ojash I posted my schema.rb

Comment: Well, the gem's [github page](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry#organising-records-into-a-tree) appears to contain pretty clear instructions. What went wrong?

Comment: @D-side if you go to the link i provided to another question you can see. I just cant get the tree to nest. I can have the parents and child all inline with one another but i just cant get it to look like parent then its subcategories below it, then another parent then its subcategories. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31559244/how-to-create-a-tree-with-ancestry-gem

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using [awesome_nested_set](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set) gem that supports nesting, and it has nice documentation, and a list of all [methods](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set/wiki/Awesome-nested-set-cheat-sheet)